# (Icon) helpers in views/templates (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I'm trying to get a grip on CodeIgniter. In my view I use the template parser, like this:

```
{blog_entries}
<h5>{title}</h5>
<p>{body}</p>
{/blog_entries}
```

Now I want to use an icon font to display icons within a blog entry. This icon font may change in the future so I want to create an icon font helper (and I think I know how do that). Writing for example `edit_icon('span')` would produce the HTML `<span class="icon">*</span>` where `*` is whatever character that gives me an edit icon.

My question is: should this helper be used in the view or in the controller? This `<span>` would obviously need a link around it. So should I go about it like this:

```
{blog_entries}
<h5>{title} <a href="{edit_link}"><?php echo edit_icon('span') ?></a></h5>
<p>{body}</p>
{/blog_entries}
```

or should the whole `<a href="{edit_link}"><?php echo edit_icon('span') ?></a>` be saved in the `$data` variable and passed on to the parser? How would you go about it?

Comment: View is not a template. Since you have no view to begin with , there is no place to put it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that an icon is specific to a view, however if you think you would use the helper for output in an api or other views for the same controller such as mobile then it would need to move back to the controller so that the data has only a single origin.

Comment: I think I'd like to use it for all my controllers. Maybe it's best to have the helper only return the character so that `edit_icon()` returns i.e. `e` and then this is passed on via `$data['edit_icon'] = 'e'`. And if I would like to apply `auto_typography()` to the body text, this should also be done in the controller, right? The key is to do all PHP within the controller?

Comment: Uhh, this gives me an headache, as the blog entries are taken directly from the database. `$data['blog_entries'] = $query->result_array();` I'm following [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html) tutorial.